# Why higher compression level can result in big zip file?

Tags: python, zip

See below. A higher compression level of zlib could result in larger file size. Why? What is a reasonable good default compression level in practice?

```
$ cat main.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=-1 fileencoding=utf-8:

import sys
import zipfile
z = zipfile.ZipFile(sys.argv[1], 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, compresslevel=int(sys.argv[3]))
z.writestr(sys.argv[2], sys.stdin.read())
z.close()

$ cat main.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

tmpfile=$(mktemp -u --suffix .zip)
set -v
for((i=0;i<=9;++i)); do
    echo "==> $i <==" >&2
    seq 10000 | ./main.py "$tmpfile" hello.txt "$i"
    ls -go "$tmpfile"
done
$ ./m
./main.py  ./main.sh  
$ ./main.sh 
for((i=0;i<=9;++i)); do
    echo "==> $i <==" >&2
    seq 10000 | ./main.py "$tmpfile" hello.txt "$i"
    ls -go "$tmpfile"
done
==> 0 <==
-rw-r--r-- 1 49020 Aug 29 11:04 /tmp/mktemp/tmp.pAKYRswuW6.zip
==> 1 <==
-rw-r--r-- 1 17271 Aug 29 11:04 /tmp/mktemp/tmp.pAKYRswuW6.zip
==> 2 <==
-rw-r--r-- 1 17303 Aug 29 11:04 /tmp/mktemp/tmp.pAKYRswuW6.zip
==> 3 <==
-rw-r--r-- 1 17972 Aug 29 11:04 /tmp/mktemp/tmp.pAKYRswuW6.zip
==> 4 <==
-rw-r--r-- 1 21936 Aug 29 11:04 /tmp/mktemp/tmp.pAKYRswuW6.zip
==> 5 <==
-rw-r--r-- 1 22071 Aug 29 11:04 /tmp/mktemp/tmp.pAKYRswuW6.zip
==> 6 <==
-rw-r--r-- 1 22298 Aug 29 11:04 /tmp/mktemp/tmp.pAKYRswuW6.zip
==> 7 <==
-rw-r--r-- 1 22298 Aug 29 11:04 /tmp/mktemp/tmp.pAKYRswuW6.zip
==> 8 <==
-rw-r--r-- 1 22298 Aug 29 11:04 /tmp/mktemp/tmp.pAKYRswuW6.zip
==> 9 <==
-rw-r--r-- 1 22298 Aug 29 11:04 /tmp/mktemp/tmp.pAKYRswuW6.zip
```

Comment: There is no universal answer to this question; it will depend on the nature of that data being compressed.

Comment: You should google your question first, There is a similar question asked and down-voted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594669/zlib-compression-enlarging-file

Comment: It is a very unusual, and interesting case.

Answer (score 0):

The size difference should be measured for larger files than the size of the dictionary. Try to measure compression for the 100 Mb files. You'll see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Any compression method is based on making assumptions about the nature of the data being compressed (in particular, what kinds of patterns can be recognized & exploited); the better your data matches those assumptions, the more effective that particular technique will be.  The worse it matches, the less effective, even to the point of resulting in a "compressed" file larger than the original.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you get the same phenomenon with random data on a restricted symbol set (like in your case: '0' .. '9' plus the CR character: 11 symbols). You can achieve a better compression with a weaker string matching (the LZ77 part of Deflate), or no string matching at all !